# How to process thousands of records faster in java

Tags: java, optimization, jdbc

I have requirement where I have to fetch 5000 records from database and check the status in mongo for each Id .if status is not active than it should delete that record from SQL table . How to optimise it currently it is taking 4 mins and I am using linked list to fetch data from SQL..

Comment: It's very hard to suggest improvements if you don't show us the original code.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise putting log statements within your code timing how long each task is taking.

```
long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
    // fetch records from SQL database
long duration1=System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
System.out.println(duration1 + " ms to fetch from SQL");
```

If your initial fetch is eating up your time, then perhaps you need to add an index to your database.  If you're accessing mongo through a slow network, then running multiple queries in parallel would speed things up.  If mongo itself is slow, then perhaps you need to index the field you're querying in mongo.

Timing each operation will help you narrow down what part of your application is behaving slowly.